# Recursive strstr function

Tags: c, function, recursion

> Write the function `strstr` such that it would be a recursive function (not a wrapper for recursion) using the following signature.

In short `strstr` returns the index of where the substr appears in str first and if it wasn't found it returns -1. More [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/)

This is my attempt:

```
int strstr1(char *str, char *substr){

    if (*str == 0 || *substr == 0)//basis, if any of the strings is empty, will return -1
        return -1;
    else{
        strstr1(str + 1, substr); //forward the address of str
        if (*str == *substr)    //for each level check if the first char matches, then it should match each pair
            strstr(str + 1, substr + 1);
```

But I got stuck. I realize there might be a need for backtracking in the recursion but I have no clue on how to do it, nor how to pass the index through all levels of recursion...

Any hints or suggestions please?

Comment: Your strstr() function can call other functions. Once you have a match of the first character of str2 in str1, you could call "strmatch()" recursively as long as the next characters also match. If the whole str2 is matched, strmatch() would return success, else failure. If it returns success, you are done. If it returns failure, you progress in str1 recursively and try again once the first character matches.

Comment: @user2225104 but how would you pass the correct index through all the levels?

Comment: The original pointer or accumulator seems necessary when returning the index.

Comment: Hint: Calling strstr recursively is rather pointless if you don't look at the result that it returns.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to use a library name for user functions. I understand this is supposed to be a learning exercise, but they could have named the function `my_strstr()` or something.

Comment: @pmg yes I know, I changed it now. It's not really a big deal.

Comment: there's no need for "backtracking". You simply need to do the recursion properly, **returning the return value of recursive calls.** As in `return strstr(str + 1, substr);`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Real" strstr() returns a char * (or const char *). In C++ standard, there are 2 overloads. To avoid linker problems, I renamed strstr() to strstr1().

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int strmatch( const char *str, const char *substr)
{
    while ( '\0' != (*substr) && (*str == *substr) )
    {
        substr++;
        str++;
    }
    if( '\0' == *substr )
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}

const char * strstr1( const char *str, const char* substr)
{
    printf("strstr(%s,%s)\n", str,substr );
    if( '\0' == (*str) )
        return NULL;
    if( *str == *substr )
    {
        if( 0 == strmatch( str, substr ) )
        {
            return str; // success value or something.
        }
    }
    return strstr1( str + 1, substr );
}



int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    const char * s1 = "Hello World";
    const char * ss1 = "World";

    if( NULL != strstr1( s1, ss1 ) )
    {
        printf("%s contains %s!\n", s1, ss1 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s does not contain %s!\n", s1, ss1 );
    }

    const char * s2 = "Hello Universe";
    const char * ss2 = "World";

    if( NULL != strstr1( s2, ss2 ) )
    {
        printf("%s contains %s!\n", s2, ss2 );
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s does not contain %s!\n", s2, ss2 );
    }

    const char * s3 = "Hello World World World World";
    const char * ss3 = "World";

    const char * foo = s3;
    while( NULL != foo )
    {
        foo = strstr1( foo, ss3 );
        if( NULL != foo )
        {
            puts("another match!");
            foo = foo + strlen(ss3);
        }
        else
        {
            puts("no more matches.");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I did specify... it should return the index of where the match is. Just like the original `strstr` function (that I linked).

Comment: @kuhaku "real" strstr() returns a char *.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: Well I did specify anyway.

Comment: @kuhaku But then why did your code use int as return value? Well - here is your complete homework ;) You could write strmatch() recursively as well, btw. And last not least, C/C++ does not support tail recursion and as such, if your string gets too long, a stack overflow will occur.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following rules: If substr is an empty string, then look up the spec of strstr to find what you should return. Otherwise, if str is an empty string then return NULL. Otherwise, if strcmp (str, substr) == 0 then return str. Otherwise, return strstr (str + 1, substr).

That said, it is a rather stupid example of recursion, because in reality you would use a loop where you increase str by 1 as long as *str != '\0'.

That said, strstr is a standard library function. If you implement a function named strstr you will have undefined behaviour. If you implement a function named strstr that has a different spec than the standard library function, you end up in DS.

Comment: those rules just don't make sense. I mean, it's definitely not correct.

Comment: Look at the C standard. The rules will exactly return what the C Standard Library function strstr will return. And any other spec for a function named strstr can be fully ignored. When you say it's definitely not correct, you surely can tell me what's wrong. But I bet you can't.

Comment: Yes I know it should have a different name, also, how does an int function returns NULL or str??

Comment: @gnasher729: okay...  strcmp? you need strncmp